# Is the "English" in the name of this site an adjective of noun?

Tags: meaning, grammar, syntactic-analysis, zeugma, anacoluthon

Sorry, I cannot parse "English language and usage", at least, a similar phrase in Russian would be ungrammatical.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118094/discussion-on-question-by-anixx-is-the-english-in-the-name-of-this-site-an-adj).

Answer (score -1):

In the phrase "English Language and Usage", "English" is most definitely an adjective. The reason you're confused is because the phrase relies on implication.

Rephrase as "[the] English language and usage [of the English language]" and It should be clearer this way. The ending preposition is not used because it is overly verbose and somewhat redundant.